# DateTimeField: how to retrieve date/time in my local time

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

models.py

```
order_booking_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

while creating:

```
"order_booking_time":"2021-10-09 06:00"
```

What it stores in database:

```
"2021-10-08T18:53:17.097257+05:30"
```

So i did this in serializer.py while viewing in data

```
def get_order_booking_time(self,obj):
    date = obj.order_booking_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return str(date)
```

Output:

```
"2021-10-09 00:30:00"
```

which is not equal to what i stored in data i.e.`"2021-10-09 06:00"`

What in the way we retrieve OR store data in this `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` format with my local time

Comment: Is USE_TZ=True in settings.py?

Comment: @hldev yes USE_TZ = True in setting, but still

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue here. Django stores the datetime in UTC format.
You are accessing the data as stored in the database>

As far as I know Django uses serializers to transform datetime fields. In this case you use the (db) model directly.

Comment: Hi Erik, try to use the comment instead of the aswer box. Use the answer option if you know how to solve the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30971168)